# How do I make configure detect software in different directories?

Tags: software-installation

I wanted to install wine as a non root user into my home folder. but when i used `./configure` it gave the output

> configure: error: no suitable flex found. Please install the 'flex' package.

So I installed flex as non-root in one of my directories but still the above error message persists.

How do I make configure detect the flex I have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. 
./configure's Default search directories are the ones listed in 
PATH.

If one types
echo $PATH
a list of paths separated by colons will be printed. All that we need to do is add the new directory paths to 'PATH' so that ./configure will check in these directories also.

For example in my case I made a directory 'Install' with sub-directories 'bin','lib','include' and 'share'.

Now I use the following commands to add these directories to 'PATH'

PATH=$PATH:/install/bin:/install/lib:/install/lib:/install/share

then I run ./configure

and all is well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to install wine from a repository not from source this could help you :

[Install Wine](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Wine-on-Ubuntu)

It should solve your problem .

Comment: I do not have root access so cannot use apt get. I have to install it locally in my workstation. I am almost there but not having flex is the only hurdle I have.

Comment: you install flex from source ?

Comment: yes, in a separate directory. ./configure cannot find it as I don't know how to add this directory to ./configure's search list.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, in fact at terminal it asked me to install using below command and the OS automatically installed by downloading from the internet.

```
sudo apt install flex
```

And also it complained about missing `bison`, so below command installed bison too.

```
sudo apt install bison
```